# Call functions from already deployed contract written by Solidity using @solana/solidity Contract

Tags: solana-program, solang

I found this sample which deploys a contract and calls functions. I already compiled my solidity contract and deployed to solana devnet. Now, I need to call functions from it. Can someone modify the below code without deployment using available programid, so file and json file?
Regards,
Ferda

```
const { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Contract, Program } = require('@solana/solidity');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

const EXAMPLE_ABI = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./example.abi', 'utf8'));
const PROGRAM_SO = readFileSync('./example.so');

(async function () {
    console.log('Connecting to your local Solana node ...');
    const connection = new Connection('http://localhost:8899', 'confirmed');

    const payer = Keypair.generate();

    console.log('Airdropping SOL to a new wallet ...');
    const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');

    const program = Keypair.generate();
    const storage = Keypair.generate();

    const contract = new Contract(connection, program.publicKey, storage.publicKey, EXAMPLE_ABI, payer);

    await contract.load(program, PROGRAM_SO);

    console.log('Program deployment finished, deploying the example contract ...');

    await contract.deploy('example', [true], program, storage);

    const res = await contract.functions.foo();
    console.log('foo: ' + res.result);

    const res2 = await contract.functions.bar();
    console.log('bar: ' + res2.result);
})();
```